# How to render Custom Html module in joomla component

Tags: php, joomla

I have a custom Html Module, I need to display in a Component view. How to get the Custom Html and display it in component view.

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
// this is where you want to load your module position
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('custom');
foreach($modules as $module)
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

Tried above code.. but not getting it.
Need solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

When using `getModules()` (note the "s" on the end), I believe you define the position rather than the name. If you simply want to render 1 module, then you can use the following

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'custom' , 'Module Title Here' );
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module );
```

Comment: It also worked for me but it will work for title "social-media" and not for "Video (Upload Product)" in my site. Dnt knw what wrong i am doing. (module is published).

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mod_custom','Video (Upload Product)' );
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module );  _italic_**bold**'code'.

good thing is,
its working for module with title ("sociali-media").

Comment: mod_custom and custom, both works. But problem with title.
It works for "social-media" and "Find out more" titles. Not for title "Home (video)" , "video (upload)"..

Answer (score 1):

By using this you can show custom module on that particular page in component.

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_custom','Your module name');
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mod_custom' , 'social-media' );
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module );

Comment: If it is useful for you then, mark it as answer so it will help others too.

Comment: Have an issue here...

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mod_custom' , 'social-media'               );
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module );     

It worked for above code with title =(social-media).
It also worked for code with title =(Find out more).

But its not working for other custom module with title =(Home Video) 
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mod_custom' , 'Home Video' );

PLease help me with this.